# React lazy load failing when rendering inside a permission based function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading, react-router-dom, react-suspense

I have following code in my App.js file, the idea is to lazy load elements if they have the permissions to do so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import {
    Router,
    Switch,
    Route
  } from "react-router-dom";
import { Page404 } from './Pages/Page404';

const HomePage = React.lazy(() => import('./Pages/HomePage'));
const UserPage = React.lazy(() => import('./Pages/UserPage'));
const AboutPage = React.lazy(() => import('./Pages/AboutPage'));

function GetUsersPage(title, hasPermission){

    return (
    <div>
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
            { hasPermission ? <UserPage title={title} /> : <Page404 /> }
        </Suspense>
    </div>
    );
}
function GetAboutPage(title, hasPermission){

    return (
    <div>
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
            { hasPermission ? <AboutPage title={title} /> : <Page404 /> }
        </Suspense>
    </div>
    );
}
function GetHomePage(title, hasPermission){

    return (
    <div>
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
            { hasPermission ? <HomePage title={title} /> : <Page404 /> }
        </Suspense>
    </div>
    );
}

export default function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/about">
                    { GetAboutPage('About', true) }
                </Route>
                <Route path="/users">
                    { GetUsersPage('Customers', false) }
                </Route>
                <Route path="/">
                    { GetHomePage('Home Page', true) }
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

When I run this code I get the following React error:

**Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.**

Has anyone got any ideas on how to fix this error? Is it something to do with the lazy load library?

Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume that the missing or unused parameters in your functions is from copy/pasting code relevant to the question?  (IE: `GetHomePage(title)` includes an undeclared `permission` variable.  `GetUsersPage(title, hasPermission)` is missing `hasPermission` but includes `permission`)

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 I've updated the question, I had a couple of typos in there

Comment: can you add your pages components code?

Comment: @RezaHashemi they're just functional components

Comment: change "Router" to "BrowserRouter" and test it again.

Comment: @RezaHashemi the error has nothing to do with that piece of code you've just mentioned

Comment: can you show how to export your 404 page?

Comment: @RezaHashemi again it's a functional component

Comment: Shot in the dark: Are you sure Page404 is not exported as default?
import Page404 from './Pages/Page404';

Comment: @henrik123 yes I'm sure

Comment: Without seeing the entire code it's hard to find the exact issue. Im guessing some of the imports are not exported as default but as named exports. I've created a sandbox with a working demo https://codesandbox.io/s/green-pine-we1ps.